# Div with 50% height inside a td without javascript

Tags: html, html-table, tablelayout

Is it possible to set div height to 50% of a cell?

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/152/ (updated)

Of course, that doesn't work, but maybe there is a way to set that height for the div?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do.  Can you describe what the end result should look like?  Is this close?  http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/151/

Comment: No, sorry. All the div elements should have the same height (50% of a row height) http://jsfiddle.net/hyNWy/152/

Answer (score 1):

50% will work if the height of the containing cell is defined with a absolute value, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/xE6v7/

Comment: FYI - the statement that the cell should be like it's neighbour isn't true.

Comment: Yes, they have different height. And also I don't know the height of a cell, it should be dynamic